# Convert CoffeeScript code to LiveScript?

Tags: coffeescript, livescript

I have this valid CoffeeScript and wish to convert it to LiveScript. Can someone explain why it fails to convert? Also to give a converted one?

```
TodoCtrl = (scope) ->
  scope.addTodo = ->
    scope.todos.push
      text: scope.todoText
      done: false
    scope.todoText = ''
```

You can use this to compile CoffeeScript.

http://coffeescript.org/

You can use this to compile LiveScript.

http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the function `scope.todos.push` against an implicit block starting with an implicit object. You must use `do` in LiveScript, as it does't do this special case (just think of `do` as parentheses around the block). See https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/issues/50 for reasons.

The code you want:

```
TodoCtrl = (scope) ->
  scope.addTodo = ->
    scope.todos.push do
      text: scope.todoText
      done: false
    scope.todoText = ''
```

which is equivalent to (ie `do` is just parentheses)

```
TodoCtrl = (scope) ->
  scope.addTodo = ->
    scope.todos.push(
      text: scope.todoText
      done: false
    )
    scope.todoText = ''
```

Glad to see you using LiveScript!

Comment: Thanks! for my new project I combine LiveScript/AngularJS/Brunch.io (which uses NodeJS) as these all seem to be the best to my eyes at the moment.